# Laravel - Show all project from company that user is in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I have a system where I want to show all the projects from a company. That specific company must be the company that the logged-in user is in. This sounds relatively simple, but I can't figure out how with my current database setup because neither projects nor the user has a `project_ID`, this because I'm using an intermediate table. I've built my database structure like below

- Users

  - company_id
- Companies

  - id
- Projects

  - company_id
- Project_User

  - user_id
  - project_id

With the above setup, I made all the connections with every model except a model for `Project_User`. These models are listed below.

*User model*

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function job()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Job::class, 'job_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {

    }

    public function isCompanyOwner() {

        if(Auth::check())
            return(Auth::user()->job_id == 1);

        return false;
    }
}
```

*Project model*

```
class Project extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
}
```

*Company model*

```
class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    /*
     *
     */
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
}
```

How can I show all projects from the company that the logged user is in on my home screen? With this current DB setup?

The current Controller gets ALL projects and none particular from a specific company.

*Controller*

```
public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::all();

    return view('Project.show', compact('projects'));
}
```

Comment: a user could be part of many companies with this layout [because they could be part of projects that belong to different companies], how do you know which exact company you want to search for? .. seems like an issue

Comment: I'm looking for the company that the logged-in user is in. So say for instance the logged-in user has company_id 2. Then I'm looking for all projects that are connected to the company with the id 2

Comment: the way your structure is setup the user could be part of many companies ... if they are, which company are you trying to find the projects for?

Comment: Then I made a mistake in my setup and that changes the question. How do I make it so a user can only be in ONE company but a company can have multiple users

Comment: you are fine if you are always checking that `company_id` field on the user and not because of the project_user -> project -> company relation link, that relationship link could allow a user to be part of projects that belong to different companies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without getting technical, this would work:

```
$request->user()->company->projects;
```

Get the company for the current user then get the projects for that company.